# Print with the zebra mz 220 using android

Tags: zebra-printers

I am learning to use my MZ 220 zebra printer, i already printed a few words using the zebra setup utilities, but i need to print using android and bluetooth and i dont get it how to make it works.
Any information will be helpful.
Is there any api from zebra to help me out on android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Zebra SDK for Android devices](http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/adapt-software/zebralink-sdk-android.html).

If has support for printing via wifi and bluetooth. The SDK comes with a bunch of examples and really verbose documentation with sample code. It'll do what you need without having to do Bluetooth comm on your own